# Can you prove that $\frac{f_n}{f_{n-1}}$ converges to $2\pi$ and $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ if $f_n=\frac{1}{f_{n-1}}+f_{n-2}$ where $f_0=0$ and $f_1=2$?

Tags: radicals, fibonacci-numbers, pi

I imagine this is already found but I cannot find the proof.

The formula also works for $f_1=\sqrt{2}^{1/x}$ to get many multiples of $\pi$

Can you also prove that when $f_1=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ then $f_n$ tends to $\sqrt{n}-.5$ ?

Example for $f_1=2$

[image]

Example for $f_1=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$

[image]

Comment: In the formula of the title, did you mean to write $f_n=1/(f_{n-1}+f_{n-2})$ ? [as it reads now it means $f_n=1/f_{n-1}+f_{n-2},$ so that the quantity $f_{n-2}$ is not part of the denominator.]

Comment: No, shouldn't be part of the denominator. I tagged it with Fibonacci because of it's similarity.

Comment: I tried a few as in title and it did not look convergent. Please include your calculations for $f_n/f_{n-1}$ for some large values of $n$ and make some summary of how long it takes for the results to stabilize. [initially the values bounced around a lot.]

Comment: Will do, also the values will bounce back and forth from 2*pi and 1/(2*pi) it definitely hones in close to that by n=10,000

Comment: You've been here a while now, surely you know a question such as this [no effort shown, you couldn't even be bothered to format this nicely] goes against the MSE Guidelines. -1 and Vote-To-Close

Comment: @mike I apologize if my formatting wasn't to your standards, haven't posted in the mathematics attack in 4 years so I'm a little out of practice. I will add images tomorrow to show some of my work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave $f_1$ arbitrary; $f_{n}f_{n-1}=f_{n-1}f_{n-2}+1$ implies $f_{n}f_{n+1}=n$ (by induction). Let
$$
f_n=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac n2\right)}a_n;
$$
then $a_{n}a_{n+1}=2$, thus $a_{2n+1}=a_1$ and $a_{2n+2}=2/a_1$ for all $n$. Now the [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Stirling%27s_formula) limit
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\Gamma(x+a)}{x^a\ \Gamma(x)}=1\qquad(a\in\mathbb{R})
$$
easily gives $\displaystyle\color{blue}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f_{2n+1}}{\sqrt n}}=a_1\color{blue}{=f_1\sqrt\pi}$ and $\displaystyle\color{blue}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f_{2n}}{\sqrt n}}=\frac2{a_1}\color{blue}{=\frac2{f_1\sqrt\pi}}$.

*(An elementary alternative here is to use the [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product).)*

For $f_1=\sqrt{2/\pi}$ we get $a_n=\sqrt2$ identically, and the asymptotics of
$$
f_n=\frac{n}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm{B}\left(\frac{n+1}2,\frac12\right)=n\sqrt\frac2\pi\int_0^1\frac{x^n\,dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=n\sqrt\frac2\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-nt}\,dt}{\sqrt{e^{2t}-1}}
$$
can be obtained using [Watson's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma). The (correct) result is
$$
f_n\asymp n^{1/2}\color{red}{-\frac14 n^{-1/2}}\color{gray}{+\frac1{32}n^{-3/2}+\frac5{128}n^{-5/2}+\dots}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The question is about a slight tweak of the Fibonacci recursion.

Let the sequence $\,f_n\,$ be defined by the recursion

$$ f_n = 1/f_{n-1} + f_{n-2}. \tag1 $$

Suppose the initial values of the sequence are

$$ f_0 = x/y, \quad f_1 = y. \tag2 $$

The next few sequence terms are

$$ f_2 = \frac{1+x}y,
 f_3 = \frac{y(2+x)}{1+x},
 f_4 = \frac{(1+x)(3+x)}{y(2+x)},
 f_5 = \frac{y(2+x)(4+x)}{(1+x)(3+x)}. \tag3 $$

The numerators and denominators can be written in terms of the
Pochhammer symbol or [rising factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)

$$ x^{(n)} := x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+n-1) \tag4 $$

by the formulas

$$ f_{2n} = \frac2y\frac{((x+1)/2)^{(n)}}{((x+2)/2)^{(n-1)}}, \qquad
f_{2n+1} = y\frac{((x+2)/2)^{(n)}}{((x+1)/2)^{(n)}}. \tag5 $$

Notice the simple result that

$$ \frac{f_{n+2}}{f_n} = \frac{n+1+x}{n+x}. \tag6 $$

Equation $(5)$ implies that

$$ \frac{f_{2n+1}}{f_{2n}} = \frac{4y^2}{x^2(x+2n)}
\left(\frac{(x/2)^{(n+1)}}{((x+1)/2)^{(n)}}\right)^2. \tag7 $$

In the case that $x=0$ this simplifies to

$$ \frac{f_{2n+1}}{f_{2n}} = \frac{y^2n!^4 2^{4n}}{(2n)(2n)!^2}. \tag8 $$

Use [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)
for $n!$ to show
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f_{2n+1}}{f_{2n}} =y^2\frac{\pi}2 $
which is $2\pi$ if $y=2.$

Now use equation $(6)$ to get
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f_{n+2}}{f_n} = 1$
and thus, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f_{2n}}{f_{2n-1}} =(2\pi)^{-1}.$

This answer the question

> Can you prove that $\frac{f_n}{f_{n-1}}$ converges to $2\pi$ and $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ if $f_n=\frac{1}{f_{n-1}}+f_{n-2}$ where $f_0=0$ and $f_1=2$?

Now one answer to the other question

> Can you also prove that when $f_1=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ then $f_n$ tends to $\sqrt{n}-.5$ ?

is to use the method of undetermined coefficients. The two
limits are equal if and only if $y = f_1 = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$.
In that case, use the Ansatz

$$ {f_n}^2 = n + a_0 + a_1n^{-1} + a_2n^{-2} + \dots \tag9 $$

which must agree with equation $(6)$ using $x=0,$ which condition

$$ \left(\frac{f_{n+2}}{f_n}\right)^2 = \frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2} =
1 + 2n^{-1} + n^{-2} \tag{10} $$

uniquely determines the coefficients in equation $(9)$ to get

$$ {f_n}^2 = n - \frac12 + \frac18 n^{-1} + \frac1{16}n^{-2}
- \frac{5}{128}n^{-3} - \frac{23}{256}n^{-4} + \dots. \tag{11} $$

Take the square root to get

$$ f_n = \sqrt{n}\left(1 - \frac14 n^{-1} + \frac1{32}n^{-2}
+\frac5{128}n^{-3} -\frac{21}{2048}n^{-4} + \dots
\right). \tag{12} $$

Thus,

$$ {f_n}^2 \approx n - \frac12, \qquad
f_n \approx \sqrt{n} - \frac14 \frac1{\sqrt{n}}. \tag{13} $$

Comment: Does OP's conjecture about limits of ratios between adjacent $f_k$ follow easily from your two formulae for the $f_k$ ?

Comment: @coffeemath The correct results do follow with the help of Stirling's formula.